# Can a Quadratic have a straight line graph or can a linear equation have a parabola graph

Tags: coordinate-systems

While reading a Olympiad book about quadratic equations, I came across a question in my mind that I will express below.

Can a linear equation like ab+by=c have a parabola graph or Can a quadratic equation have a straight line graph?

Comment: Not in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: A quadratic is per definition not a straight line (the quadratic term is not allowed to vanish). I think, with the linear equation , you mean "$ax+by=c$" and this defines always a line. So the answer to both questions is "no".